# How to remove custom relationship in SugarCRM

Tags: sugarcrm

The one-to-many relationship between two modules isn't needed but there is no option in Studio to delete it.

If such tables are removed manually from the database, upon running repair and rebuild SugarCRM detects the difference between the db state and some of its saved scripts. I am referring to a relationship table like:

```
securitygroups_cards_1_c
```

So, how can a custom relationship be removed permanently from SugarCRM so that it no longer appears in repair and rebuild?

I am using SugarCRM version *6.5.20*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out. Following files need to be deleted to get rid of a custom relationship completely (please note that the process is irreversible so make sure you are deleting the correct files):

- custom\metadata\[RELATIONSHIP_NAME]MetaData.php
- custom\Extension\application\Ext\TableDictionary\[RELATIONSHIP_NAME].php
- custom\Extension\modules\[MODULE_NAME]\ext\vardef\[FIELD_NAME].php
- custom\Extension\modules\[MODULE_NAME]\ext\vardef\[FIELD_NAME].php

Run repair and rebuild and you are done.